# Constraint is not enough?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple Database consist of;

Person_id, City and is_manager columns. is_manager can have TRUE or FALSE bit (0,1).

There are some restrictions that I manage to complete, such as;

1. each city can have one or more than one person (unique
   person_id+City)
2. each person can be either manager or not in a city. (unique person+city+is_manager)
3. each city can have only one manager
   but can have more than one non-managers.
4. not every person has to have a city, some might not be assigned to a
   city at all.

I managed to do first two constraints easily but I couldn't manage for the third condition. because each city can have one manager, but can have more than one non_manager positions.

I have some other methodology to solve it but it will be not 100% on server-side solution. I want to have 100% SQL Server side solution.

I think it can be done with trigger;

- if so, how? (when is_manager TRUE comes, search whole database for that if city has any manager before, if not accept data, otherwise don't accept)
- if not necessary, how with constraints?

Comment: Remove  the `is_manager` column from the table. Add `manager_id` to the `City` table.

Comment: Seems a unique filtered index should be sufficient.

Comment: @Serg one person cannot be non-manager and manager at the same city, how can I control it with two different tables then?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could you explain it a bit more please?

Comment: Can a person have more than one city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample DB

```
create table Person(
    id int primary key,
    cityId int,
    constraint UK1 unique(cityId, id)
);


create table City (
    id int primary key,
    managerId int,
    constraint FK1 foreign key(id, managerId) references Person(cityId, id)
);
```

Business process is first assign a person to a City then make him/her a manager of the City.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b67114b3fd72bd06b2ce0b4f97a03476) including test data

Comment: Thanks for the answer; but not every person has to be assigned to a city, some person does not have to have a city. first table forces that every person has to be assigned to a city.

Comment: No, CityId is not declared NOT NULL. You can insert a person without a City but this person cann not be a City  manager. Added  a fiddle.

Comment: thanks :) I think this solves the problem.

Comment: @Oray If this does answer you question, you might consider accepting the answer.